# call a method every specific ms

Tags: java, libgdx

I am developing a game in LibGDX, and i want to call my update function every ms.

But I don't know how to make it in my case -

```
while(gameLoop) {
  renderWorld();
}

public void renderWorld() {
  // Some rendering code here
  if(world.map[mapPos].ID == 9) {
    updateWater(mapPos); // This function makes the water animate, but i must put a time limit otherwise it will be too hard to see the animation, how can i limit this?
  }
}
```

As you can see i want to update the water, and i can't do this without time limit because otherwise the water "animation" will be too quick to even see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well want to take a look at [com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html)

Where you can simply use,

```
float delay = 0.5f; // seconds

Timer.schedule(new Task(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your work
        if(world.map[mapPos].ID == 9) {
            updateWater(mapPos);
        }
    }
}, delay, delay);
```

This will be executed on main thread repeatedly at an interval of 500 ms.
So there will be no problem in gwt version as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: uhh.. i dont want to render the world every 500 ms i want to updateWater every 500 ms look at my code, plus i need to pass variable `mapPos` to the function. now tell me how i gonna do that.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion there is a better way to solve this. Since you always update everything by the delta time you can simply sum up the times. If the time is above your 500ms you update it and reset the timer to 0. Of cause the update wouldn't always be exactly at 500ms but you shouldnt notice it if your logic doesn't go under the 60 Frames.

I wouldn't use a Thread or a Timer for it.

Here is a quic example for it:

```
@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    // sum the deltas
    sum += delta;
    // time to update?
    if (sum >= update_time){
       //update the map here and set the update_time to the 500ms for example
    }
}
```

That would be a kind of timer without using the Timer class and using the regular libgdx "system". In this case the Map could be an Actor and you regulary update it with overriding the act method as shown above. (`Stage-Actor-System` from the `Sceen2D` Framework from libgdx)
Call the Act as usual inside of the `public void render(float delta) {...}`.

If you want to use timer take a look at the Timerclass from libgdx. [Link to the Timer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html)

Comment: ok.. but how can i pass the parameter i want? `mapPos` look at the code i wrote.

Comment: The actor should have a mapPos i think. You shouldn't pass it at the act method. The act is just to update the actor not to pass any references.

Comment: ok i will try it.. it sounds kinds weird.. i will update you :)